# Replicator filter for already consumed messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Why does confluent replicator replicate messages which are already consumed ? There are many use cases where a message is not needed on the topic once consumed. Is n't it a good idea to filter out already-consumed messages (provided there is a consumer-registry of some sort)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't replicate messages already consumed if the offsets are being commited correctly back for the consumer group of the Replicator

Messages consumed by your other processes doesn't remove them from the Kafka topic, and when Replicator is part of another consumer group, it wouldn't know what's consumed